# DataflowEx never completes

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I am trying to use the open source lib [DataflowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx) with the next Dataflow declaration.

```
class RequestClientFlow :Dataflow<string>{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly Dataflow<string, WebProxy> _webproxyDataflow;
    private readonly Dataflow<WebProxy, HttpClient> _httpClientDataflow;

    public RequestClientFlow(ILogger logger) : this(DataflowOptions.Default){
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Dataflow<WebProxy, HttpClient> HttpClientDataflow => _httpClientDataflow;

    public RequestClientFlow(DataflowOptions dataflowOptions) : base(dataflowOptions){
        _webproxyDataflow = new TransformBlock<string,WebProxy>(s => {
            _logger.WriteLine("aaaa");
            return new WebProxy();
        }).ToDataflow();
        _httpClientDataflow = new TransformBlock<WebProxy,HttpClient>(proxy => {
            _logger.WriteLine("bbbb");
            return new HttpClient();
        }).ToDataflow();
        _webproxyDataflow.LinkTo(_httpClientDataflow);
        RegisterChild(_webproxyDataflow);
        RegisterChild(_httpClientDataflow);
    }

    public override ITargetBlock<string> InputBlock => _webproxyDataflow.InputBlock;
}
```

when I consume it like

```
var requestClientFlow = new RequestClientFlow(this);
requestClientFlow.Post("");
requestClientFlow.Complete();
await requestClientFlow.InputBlock.Completion;
```

it completes and my output displays

> 18:32:54.3773|aaaa   18:32:54.3773|bbbb
>
> 1 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, took 1.45 seconds (xUnit.net 2.3.1
>   build 3858).

However my understand is from the framework docs that i should also be able to use

```
    requestClientFlow.Complete();
    await requestClientFlow.CompletionTask;
```

or even

```
await requestClientFlow.SignalAndWaitForCompletionAsync();
```

it does not complete. Can someone please help me understand what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flow cannot complete since the last block is a `TransformBlock`. In your first example you `await` completion of the *Input* block which does in fact complete. The *Output* block cannot complete as the items in its output buffer have nowhere to go. The `DataflowEx` library is correctly `awaiting` on the final block in the flow. You can add an `ActionBlock` or `NullTarget` to the end to realize completion.

In terms of `DataflowEx` the final flow should be implmeneting

```
public interface IDataflow<in TIn> : IDataflow
{
    ITargetBlock<TIn> InputBlock { get; }
}
```

And as the example on the [github](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx) page for the library shows:

```
public class AggregatorFlow : Dataflow<string>
{
    //...//

    public AggregatorFlow() : base(DataflowOptions.Default)
    {
        _splitter = new TransformBlock<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>>(s => this.Split(s));
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        //***Note The ActionBlock here***
        _aggregater = new ActionBlock<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(p => this.Aggregate(p));

        //Block linking
        _splitter.LinkTo(_aggregater, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        /* IMPORTANT */
        RegisterChild(_splitter);
        RegisterChild(_aggregater);
    }

    //...//
}
```

Comment: hmm thnks for the answer but still hard to get it. Using an ActionBlock does not allow me to expose the transformed objects into another reusable component or dataflow right? so could you please demo the DataflowBlock.NullTarget option?

Comment: Neither `ActionBlock` or the `NullTarget` will let you flow the produced `HttpClient` into another flow. If that's your requirement then your flow needs to be a `Dataflow<string, HttpClient>`. And in your test you can link that flow using `LinkLeftToNull()` from `DataflowEx`. See [#5 Advanced Linking](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx)

Comment: Also note that the example doesn't call `ToDataflow()` on the underlying blocks and explicitly propagates completion between the inner blocks with  `DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true }`